# how does NODE_ENV work

Tags: npm, npm-install

in packages.json I see scripts set to be run under specific environments .

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "node_modules/.bin/gulp build; NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --display-error-details",
    "bower": "node_modules/.bin/bower",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest" , .....
```

my questions are :

1-where are these environments declared ?

2-what is the difference between `NODE_ENV=test` and `NODE_ENV=development` ?

3-how does npm understand them and how can it tell what is my current environment?

4- can you explain differences between how and when to run the mentioned scripts

Comment: Is that a typo? `NODE_ENV=test` is equal to `NODE_ENV=test`

Comment: oh yes @httpNick ! Thank you edited , I want to know the difference between NODE_ENV=test and NODE_ENV=development , please to see all 4 questions

Comment: I am interested in the answer to this as well since I do not know. Just something I noticed :-)